# Merging objects on javascript gives me nested object, how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working with these notes using AsyncStorage, my issue comes after I concat the new data, it gets added as nested object, that's not what I expected so the code looks like

```
addNote = async () => {
    try {
      var id = this.props.navigation.state.params.data.vhq_id;
      var raw = await AsyncStorage.getItem("notes");
      var value = JSON.parse(raw);

      if (value === null) {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem(
          "notes",
          JSON.stringify({ text: this.state.userinput, id: id })
        );
      } else {
        var note = {
          text: this.state.userinput,
          id: id,
        };
        var newData = { value, note };
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(newData));
      }
    } catch (erorr) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  };
```

The output I have

```
Object {
  "note": Object {
    "id": "c62eb2fe-1647-4e9e-ad21-ce0fb0216948",
    "text": "Cccc",
  },
  "value": Object {
    "note": Object {
      "id": "c62eb2fe-1647-4e9e-ad21-ce0fb0216948",
      "text": "Bbbb",
    },
    "value": Object {
      "id": "c62eb2fe-1647-4e9e-ad21-ce0fb0216948",
      "text": "Aaaa",
    },
  },
}
```

I am not sure why this is happening, I tried adding the object directly on the concat function without using it as variable but it seems it's the wrong syntax

```
 var newData = 
 { 
 value, 
 {text: this.state.userinput,
 id: id}
 };
```

Comment: What would be the expected result? You are storing `value` inside `newData`. That is the expected result. Also, this question seem very obvious to debug, what have  you tried, and what worked, and what did not work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want `notes` to be an array and if theres already a note in `AsyncStorage` you want to append a new note to the array. So you might want to try this

```
addNote = async () => {
    try {
      var id = this.props.navigation.state.params.data.vhq_id;
      var raw = await AsyncStorage.getItem("notes");
      var value = JSON.parse(raw);

      if (value === null) {
        await AsyncStorage.setItem(
          "notes",
          JSON.stringify([{ text: this.state.userinput, id: id }]) // See that this is setting an array item to the notes
        );
      } else {
        var note = {
          text: this.state.userinput,
          id: id,
        };
        var newData = [ ...value, note ]; // newData is a new array with all items in the value array plus the new note object
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("notes", JSON.stringify(newData));
      }
    } catch (erorr) {
      console.log(error.message);
    }
  };
```